# Convert complex HTML menu to Wordpress

Tags: menus

I know this question has been asked a few times, but after a lot of research I can't seem to find the answer.

The main question is: how do I convert this HTML menu to Wordpress? I don't really care if it's static, i.e. I don't *have* to dynamically put in into Wordpress via the admin back-end, but it won't work if it's static, because I can't give a menu item a class to know to that it's active, since I won't know which page will be active. And I can't create a different php file for every single page on my website.

When converting it to Wordpress, I don't know how to implement the dividers...

This is the code of my menu. I also have a button to open and close it and Jquery to enable that, but I don't think that's useful right now.

```
 <nav id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
        <div class="main-menu-top">
            <div class="main-menu-search"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div>
            <div class="main-menu-logo"><a href="/"><img src="logo.png" alt"website title" title="website title"></div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-menu-panel">
            <ul>
                <li class="main-menu-item">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-home"></span>Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-calendar-plus"></span>Updates</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item main-menu-item-before-divider">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-comments"></span>Live</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item main-menu-item-divider">
                    Berichten
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-tv"></span>Televisie</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item main-menu-item-selected">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-film"></span>Film</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item main-menu-item">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-headphones"></span>Radio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item main-menu-item-before-divider">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span>Andere</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item main-menu-item-divider">
                    Database
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-tv"></span>Televisie</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item main-menu-item">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-film"></span>Film</a>
                </li>
                <li class="main-menu-item">
                    <a href="/"><span class="fas fa-headphones"></span>Radio</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-menu-bottom">
            <div class="main-menu-bottom-social social-mail">
                <a href="mailto:myemail"><span class="fas fa-envelope"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-bottom-social social-facebook">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/myfacebook" target="_blank"><span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu-bottom-social social-twitter">
                <a href="https://www.twitter.com/mytwitter" target="_blank"><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The menu looks like this:

[image: How the menu looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just another normal menu. You can use CSS class in menus to add custom CSS `main-menu-item-before-divider` for menu item which acts as divider in CSS class field which can be activated under **Screen Options** tab at the top of Menu page.
You can create another custom field for font awesome classes for menus. With little modification of code form [here](https://gist.github.com/kucrut/3804376).

```
<?php
/**
 * Proof of concept for how to add new fields to nav_menu_item posts in the WordPress menu editor.
 * @author Weston Ruter (@westonruter), X-Team
 */

add_action( 'init', array( 'XTeam_Nav_Menu_Item_Custom_Fields', 'setup' ) );

class XTeam_Nav_Menu_Item_Custom_Fields {
    static $options = array(
        'item_tpl' => '
            <p class="additional-menu-field-{name} description description-thin">
                <label for="edit-menu-item-{name}-{id}">
                    {label}<br>
                    <input
                        type="{input_type}"
                        id="edit-menu-item-{name}-{id}"
                        class="widefat code edit-menu-item-{name}"
                        name="menu-item-{name}[{id}]"
                        value="{value}">
                </label>
            </p>
        ',
    );

    static function setup() {
        if ( !is_admin() )
            return;

        $new_fields = apply_filters( 'xteam_nav_menu_item_additional_fields', array() );
        if ( empty($new_fields) )
            return;
        self::$options['fields'] = self::get_fields_schema( $new_fields );

        add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', function () {
            return 'XTeam_Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit';
        });
        //add_filter( 'xteam_nav_menu_item_additional_fields', array( __CLASS__, '_add_fields' ), 10, 5 );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( __CLASS__, '_save_post' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    static function get_fields_schema( $new_fields ) {
        $schema = array();
        foreach( $new_fields as $name => $field) {
            if (empty($field['name'])) {
                $field['name'] = $name;
            }
            $schema[] = $field;
        }
        return $schema;
    }

    static function get_menu_item_postmeta_key($name) {
        return '_menu_item_' . $name;
    }

    /**
     * Inject the 
     * @hook {action} save_post
     */
    static function get_field( $item, $depth, $args ) {
        $new_fields = '';
        foreach( self::$options['fields'] as $field ) {
            $field['value'] = get_post_meta($item->ID, self::get_menu_item_postmeta_key($field['name']), true);
            $field['id'] = $item->ID;
            $new_fields .= str_replace(
                array_map(function($key){ return '{' . $key . '}'; }, array_keys($field)),
                array_values(array_map('esc_attr', $field)),
                self::$options['item_tpl']
            );
        }
        return $new_fields;
    }

    /**
     * Save the newly submitted fields
     * @hook {action} save_post
     */
    static function _save_post($post_id, $post) {
        if ( $post->post_type !== 'nav_menu_item' ) {
            return $post_id; // prevent weird things from happening
        }

        foreach( self::$options['fields'] as $field_schema ) {
            $form_field_name = 'menu-item-' . $field_schema['name'];
            // @todo FALSE should always be used as the default $value, otherwise we wouldn't be able to clear checkboxes
            if (isset($_POST[$form_field_name][$post_id])) {
                $key = self::get_menu_item_postmeta_key($field_schema['name']);
                $value = stripslashes($_POST[$form_field_name][$post_id]);
                update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
            }
        }
    }

}

// @todo This class needs to be in it's own file so we can include id J.I.T.
// requiring the nav-menu.php file on every page load is not so wise
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php';
class XTeam_Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit extends Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [], $id = 0) {
        $item_output = '';
        parent::start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args, $id);
        // Inject $new_fields before: <div class="menu-item-actions description-wide submitbox">
        if ( $new_fields = XTeam_Nav_Menu_Item_Custom_Fields::get_field( $item, $depth, $args ) ) {
            $item_output = preg_replace('/(?=<div[^>]+class="[^"]*submitbox)/', $new_fields, $item_output);
        }
        $output .= $item_output;
    }
}


// Somewhere in config...
add_filter( 'xteam_nav_menu_item_additional_fields', 'mytheme_menu_item_additional_fields' );
function mytheme_menu_item_additional_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['fa-class'] = array(
        'name' => 'fa-class',
        'label' => __('Font Awesome Class', 'xteam'),
        'container_class' => 'fa-class',
        'input_type' => 'text',
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

After adding the above code you should able to see another custom field for font awesome classes where you can put fa classes as `fas fa-tv`
Then you can use walker nav class as below.

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ){ //ul
        $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){ //li a span

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t",$depth) : '';

        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'main-menu-item'; // common class for li items
        $classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active main-menu-item-selected ' : ''; // Add selected class for current menu item
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if( $depth && $args->walker->has_children ){
            $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
        }

        $class_names =  join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'.$item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';

        $attributes .= ( $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';


        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';

        $fa_class = get_post_meta($item->ID,'_menu_item_fa-class',true) ?: false;  // Get font awesome class
        if( $fa_class ){

            $item_output .= '<span class="'.$fa_class.'"></span>'; // Add span if the fa classes exists

        }

        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ( $depth == 0 && $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' <b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters ( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

    }

}
```

Then you can use `wp_nav_menu()` to get the menu

```
  wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main', 'container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mymenu">%3$s</ul>' , 'walker' => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Primary()));     // you may need to change some args as per your requirement for example "menu" => "Some menu"
```

Comment: Thank you! It actually worked, with a little bit of modification.